# Excel CSV numbers to normal string for PHP

Tags: php, excel, csv, numbers

I'm working on an import module where an admin can import rows of client information (including the client's ID Number which is a 13 digit numeric value) from a CSV file.

The problem appears that Excel converts the numbers to look like 8.88888E+12 if the value was 8888881111088 and I need to validate that number (even if it's a string) to match back to a previous entry in the database).

Unfortunately I cannot rely on the admin to convert these entries within Excel to a string so I am looking for a way in PHP to convert the incorrect values to a 13-digit number/string.

Any suggestions would greatly be appreciated!

Here is a sample of the script I am using:

```
 <?php
 // $data contains the rows returned from the CSV file:
 foreach ($data AS $k => $v) {
      /* $v['id_number'] is 8.88888E+12 but in the database it's stored correctly
       * as 888888111088. I need to match the imported value from the CSV to the row
       * in the database.
       * 
       * I need to convert 8.88888E+12 back to 888888111088.
       */
      if (strlen(str_replace(" ", "", $v['id_number'])) != 13) {
            $this->importValidateRules[$k] = "The ID number (" . $v['id_number'] . ") is invalid. It must be 13 characters long.";
      }
      // Continue with model validation:
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: It can not be done if it is saved incorrectly as a csv. Open it in notepad and see how it is represented in the flat file. If it was an xls or xlsx file you could get the original value. But not once save incorrectly in a csv.

Comment: @RobbieChiha Thank you for your feedback, I thought as much :(

Comment: Play with field types in Excel, then try reexporting to CSV. You can also try to use `PHPExcel`, works great.

Comment: @MauritzSwanepoel if you want to understand the maths of it:
8.88888E+12 = 8.88888*10^12 = 8888880000000 
Which does not convert back the full number. The only way is to have it a text field in excel before saving.

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. I have officially lost 5 hours of my life thanks to Excel haha. Unfortunately I have to do the validation bit in the code as I cannot rely on the client to manipulate the data before the time. I'm going to look at phpExcel as an answer here!

Answer (score 0):

In general putting ' sign in cell before the number could enforce Excel to use the value as text. If you could manipulate the original xls or ask user to do it before saving to csv it would work {e.g. having a new column in and putting onto B1 cell =CONCATENATE("'",A1) }
"Figuring out" from csv+php won't work (precision lost already).